# Iterate on req.body.objectName to test whether the key-value pairs are valid or not in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

the problem statement is something like this :
**"the node js webservice server application should first validate whether the req.body.object contains valid key-value pairs, if its present then only go to mongodb specific method and do some CRUD operation and send response otherwise send response as key-value pairs are not correct or something similar."**

So, for achieving this, I tried putting things like the below one at the route:

```
if ((updatevalues.ConfigID == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigName == null) || (updatevalues.Description == null) || (updatevalues.Version == null) || (updatevalues.ClassName == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.AllEvents == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.BillingDateCleard == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.BillingScheduleExpiration == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.ConfigurationErrorDetected == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.DailySelfReadTime == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.DataVineHyperSproutChange == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.DataVineSyncFatherChange == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.Demand == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.DemandResetOccured == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.DeregistrationResult == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.EnableVoltageMonitor == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.Energy1 == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.HighVoltageThresholdDeviation == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.HistoryLogCleared == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.InterrogationSendSucceeded == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.IntervalLength == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.LinkFailure == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.LinkMetric == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.LoadProfileError == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.LowBatteryDetected == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.LowVoltageThreshold == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.LowVoltageThresholdDeviation == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.OutageLength == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.PrimaryPowerDown == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.PulseWeight1 == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.PulseWeight2 == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.PulseWeight3 == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.PulseWeight4 == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.Quantity4 == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.RMSVoltHighThreshold == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.RMSVoltLoadThreshold == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.ReceivedMessageFrom == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.SendResponseFailed == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.TableSendRequestFailed == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.TestModeDemandIntervalLength == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.TimetoremaininTestMode == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.ZigbeeSETunnelingMessage == null) || (updatevalues.ConfigGroups_Info.ZigbeeSimpleMeteringMessage == null)) {

    res.json({
        "type": false,
        "Status": "Invalid Parameter"
    });
}
else {

    dbCmd.updateConfigDataValues(updatevalues, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                "type": false,
                "Message": err.message,
            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                "type": true,
                "Message": data.toString(),
            });
        }
    });
}
```

});

```
module.exports = router;
```

What I feel is this is not the right or optimized way to achieving the above said objective. **I want to compact/compress the If condition so that code could look better**. 
kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the fields in array like that:

```js
let fields = [
'ConfigID',
'ConfigName',
'ConfigGroups_Info.AllEvents'
...];

if (_.some(fields, f => _.get(updatevalues, f) === null)) {
res.json({
        "type": false,
        "Status": "Invalid Parameter"
    });
}
else ...
```

BTW, you probably want to make sure that the fields are present, so checking if they are null is not correct. If the field is missing, it is `undefined` not `null`. You can just check that `!_.get(updatevalues, f)`. It will be true for null, undefined, 0, empty string and false. If it is too much you need to check what you need specifically, like null and undefined.

Comment: hi , thanks for the reply. Sorry for being late . Can you please give more simple solution which could easily be understood ?

Comment: This is the simplest I can think of. What don't you understand?

Comment: regarding this underscore notation, "if (_.some(fields, f => _.get(updatevalues, f) === null)) " , could you please provide some URL to read more about it ? is it from underscore.js npm package ? I actually could not get chance to work on underscore.js.

Comment: I think it's something any js developer should know. The `get` is exactly like `updateValues.f` but it won't fail if updateValues is null or undefined. The `some` returns true if the function in the second argument return true for any of the values in the first argument `fields`. https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0

Comment: thanks for the quick replys. :) I will read more about it and will connect to you if required.